# Magento 1.9 - Where is called addAction()?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, addtocart

I'm studying the process of add to cart of Magento and I would like to know the addAction() function...where is invoked and who calls this function?? This function is active after the validation in abstract.php right?

I studied the process to the function getProductUrl() and do not understand how to continue the process of add to cart after this function.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `addAction()` of which class? There are a dozen method named `addAction`. Which `Abstract.php`?

Comment: You're right...I mean the addAction() of CartController.php, the function that places the products in the cart of the class Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addAction` is a controller action.
You should get familiarized with the MVC of Magento or MVC in general.
the add to cart url looks like this: `checkout/cart/add`.
This means the url will call the methdod `addAction` from the `CartController` from the `Checkout` module.

```
checkout/cart/add
   |      |    |
   |      |    |---action
   |      |--Controller
   |--Module
```